# how can I modify browser word wrap behavior?

Tags: javascript, html

I notice that when the browser (firefox, safari) wraps text, the *space* where it breaks to wrap (the last space of a line) gets turned into a zero-width space, i.e, when you create a mouse selection across multiple lines in a paragraph, the *space* where it breaks does not visibly show. Is it possible to change this behavior so that the breaking *space* retains its width?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a guess but I would say no. This is a fundamental way in which the browser works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using a font where the zero-width space character is designed having the width of a normal space. You may use [Fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) to create own fonts or to modify existing fonts. It is free and mighty, but takes some time to get used too.